# I am not able to use cuda on my Pytorch model. It's saying i didn't set my loss function to cuda but I did set it to cuda

Tags: pytorch

it's showing some inbuilt error in loss function when I try to set it to cuda

here's my code:

```
losses = []
loss_function = nn.NLLLoss().to(device=device)
model = NGramLanguageModeler(len(vocab), EMBEDDING_DIM, CONTEXT_SIZE).to(device= device)
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

```
for epoch in range(1):
    total_loss = 0
    for context, target in ngrams:

        # Step 1. Prepare the inputs to be passed to the model (i.e, turn the words
        # into integer indices and wrap them in tensors)
        context_idxs = torch.tensor([word_to_ix[w] for w in context], dtype=torch.long).to(device= device)

        # Step 2. Recall that torch *accumulates* gradients. Before passing in a
        # new instance, you need to zero out the gradients from the old
        # instance
        model.zero_grad()

        # Step 3. Run the forward pass, getting log probabilities over next
        # words
        log_probs = model(context_idxs).to(device= device)

        # Step 4. Compute your loss function. (Again, Torch wants the target
        # word wrapped in a tensor)
        loss = (loss_function(log_probs, torch.tensor([word_to_ix[target]], dtype=torch.long))).to(device= device)
        # Step 5. Do the backward pass and update the gradient
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Get the Python number from a 1-element Tensor by calling tensor.item()
        total_loss += loss.item()
    losses.append(total_loss)
print(losses)  # The loss decreased every iteration over the training data!
```

and here's the error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ed227a0e464c> in <module>
     18         # Step 4. Compute your loss function. (Again, Torch wants the target
     19         # word wrapped in a tensor)
---> 20         loss = (loss_function(log_probs, torch.tensor([word_to_ix[target]], dtype=torch.long))).to(device= device)
     21         # Step 5. Do the backward pass and update the gradient
     22         loss.backward()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2699     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2700         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2701     return torch._C._nn.nll_loss_nd(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2702 
   2703 

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument target in method wrapper_nll_loss_forward)
```

Answer (score 0):

`torch.tensor([word_to_ix[target]])` is still on cpu.